# Object.setXXX(Spring Data JPA Entity) throws NullPointerException

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am facing Spring Data JPA underlying object problem. If there is an object and calls its setter method and if the parameter could be entity returned by JpaRepository, it throws NullPointerException.

Entity *Cheat*

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cheat")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"vote"})
@NoArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
public class Cheat implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "cheat_seq", length = 10)
    private Long cheatSeq;

    @Column(name = "question", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String question;

    @Column(name = "answer", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String answer;

    @Column(name = "writer_ip", nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private String writerIP;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "reg_date", nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    private Date regDate;

    @Transient
    @NonNull
    private String regDateText;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cheat", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<CheatVote> vote = new HashSet<CheatVote>();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cheat [cheatSeq=" + cheatSeq + "]";
    }


}
```

And entity *CheatVote* which is a @ManyToOne collection from *Cheat*, is below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="cheat_vote")
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Getter
@Setter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CheatVote implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name="seq", nullable=false)
    private Long seq;

    @Column(name="val", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private Integer value;

    @Column(name="ip_address", nullable=false)
    @NonNull
    private String ipAddress;

    @JoinColumn(name="cheat_fk", referencedColumnName="cheat_seq")
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @NonNull
    private Cheat cheat;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "CheatVote [seq=" + seq + "]";
    }


}
```

Service layer is below:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class CheatVoteServiceImpl implements CheatVoteService{

    @Autowired
    private CheatVoteRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    private CheatService cheatService;

    @Override
    public void addGoodVote(Long cheatSeq, String ipAddress) throws NotFoundEntityException {
        Cheat cheat = cheatService.findOne(cheatSeq);

        CheatVote vote = new CheatVote();
        vote.setCheat(cheat);
        vote.setValue(CheatVoteRepository.VOTE_TYPE_GOOD);
        vote.setIpAddress(ipAddress);

        Set<CheatVote> votes = new HashSet<CheatVote>();
        votes.add(vote);
        cheat.setVote(votes);
        cheatService.addCheat(cheat);
        repository.save(vote);
    }
}
```

Repository layer is below:

```
public interface CheatVoteRepository extends JpaRepository<CheatVote, Long>{
    Integer VOTE_TYPE_GOOD = 1;

}
```

Test code is below:

```
@Test
    public void voteTest() throws Exception{
        cheatService.addCheat(addDTO1);
        Cheat cheat = cheatService.findAll().get(0);
        assertEquals(0, cheat.getVote().size());

        cheatVoteService.addGoodVote(cheat.getCheatSeq(), "127.0.0.1");
    }
```

Two DTO objects are below. One is :

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CheatAddNewDTO {

    private String ipAddress;
    private List<CheatUnit> unitList;
}
```

And the other one is:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor(staticName="of")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class CheatUnit {

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @Mapping("question")
    private String question;

    @NotNull
    @NonNull
    @Mapping("answer")
    private String answer;

}
```

It throws *NullPointerException*:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: cheat
    at com.ddedderu.moonBladeQuiz.data.entity.CheatVote.setCheat(CheatVote.java:29)
    at com.ddedderu.moonBladeQuiz.data.service.CheatVoteServiceImpl.addGoodVote(CheatVoteServiceImpl.java:31)
    at com.ddedderu.moonBladeQuiz.data.service.CheatVoteServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d089e475.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:736)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:671)
    at com.ddedderu.moonBladeQuiz.data.service.CheatVoteServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b1f41534.addGoodVote(<generated>)
    at com.ddedderu.moonBladeQuiz.MoonBladeQuizApplicationTests.voteTest(MoonBladeQuizApplicationTests.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

After seeing that error stacks, I got thinking that when the entity is set in something object's setter method, its proxy object (maybe used with AOP skill) does something to deal with JPA internal system.

But why do I have to even consider that underlying part of JPA ?
Or is that error stack comes because of my malformed entity structure?
What went wrong?

**And I am sorry that I can not react on your comment quickly !**

**Feel free to require any code related with this question !**

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The NPE doesn't come from JPA nor Spring Data JPA.

It is simply that in these three lines:

```
    Cheat cheat = cheatService.findOne(cheatSeq);

    CheatVote vote = new CheatVote();
    vote.setCheat(cheat);
```

The cheat doesn't get found and therefore is `null` and when you call `vote.setCheat` the Lombok [`@NonNull`](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull) annotation takes effect and throws an exception.

To fix the problem do one of the following:

- check that `cheat` is non-null before setting it.
- remove the `@NonNull` annotation.

Comment: Thank you really, again, I have to cut off Lombok code. I already removed @Data annotation which causes exception for some reason before.

Comment: At least, in this case, Lombok was doing exactly what it promised to do.